# clicking or scrolling on terminal outputs text

Tags: unix, terminal, cygwin

this is driving me crazy. Everytime I click on the terminal, I get text output but the click does not happen. I can't select anything, scroll on the terminal or perform any mouse operations.

For example, if I click I get things like `"TB#TB"`, which is `"TB"` when I click and `"#TB"` when I release the click. If I scroll I get `'`UC'` for every scroll of the wheel. Total rubbish.

I'm using cygwin to connect to a redhat machine and it happens only for this one machine. If I connect to a different one, also running redhat, it doesn't happen, so I think the issue is on the remote machine's side. It's also independent of what shell I'm using.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I discovered that pressing shift returns all the usual mouse functionality. I wonder why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like a "come down to your machine and solve problem"

You must have save default setting for that particular machine to direct it to shift option. As you said shift solves the problem.

You should reset the settings.
go here.
Putty configuration>windows>selection>click on shift overrides application's use of mouse

hope this helps

Comment: It´s cygwin, but it´s not there since logging into a different machine does not exhibit this behaviour. Also, I don´t find that option in the cygwin terminal.

Comment: hmm Cygwin I used long ago... but I do remember seeing the same option there not sure tho... since you are saying it one machine one area to look may be the .profile file.. loading a different environment.... do a `diff` between this and other servers if you can....